# Is it possible to deploy more then one Strapi.io app on the same Heroku dyno?

Tags: heroku, strapi

I read more tutorials about deploy Strapi to Heroku and all of them talks about deployng your Strapi app to Heroku. But in addition I would like to understand if it is possible to deploy for example 2 different Strapi applications, to the same Heroku dyno and if it has any disadvantage or not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

You need to use  [Nginx Virtual Host](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/deployment/nginx-proxy.html#nginx-virtual-host) as defined in Strapi Nginx Proxying documentation.

It's mentioned in [Amazon AWS part of the documentation](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/deployment/amazon-aws.html#further-steps-to-take).

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-with-http-2-support-on-ubuntu-18-04